client.join() is not a function Nestjs+socket.io
I'm working with websockets in NestJS with socket.io , I have followed the NestJs documentation to write this handler that's supposed to let a user join a room.
  @SubscribeMessage('joinQuiz')
  handleJoinQuiz(@MessageBody() data: JoinQuizDto, @ConnectedSocket() client: Socket): boolean {
    const { quizCode, playerName, avatar } = data;
    const result = this.quizSessionService.joinQuiz(quizCode, client.id, playerName,this.quizzes);
    if (result) {
      client.join(quizCode)
      this.server.to(quizCode).emit('playerJoined', { id: client.id, playerName, avatar });
    } else {
      client.emit('errorMsg', 'Failed to join quiz.');
    }
    return (result)
  }

When I call this  websocket ednpoint on postman ws://localhost:300 and send this message
{
  "event": "joinQuiz",
  "data": {
   "quizCode": "774add9c-5aee-49cb-b2da-a5aa76c79880",
    "playerName": "lacy",
    "avatar": "url"
  }
}

I get  this error:
[Nest] 4528  - 04/05/2024 14:39:44   ERROR [WsExceptionsHandler] client.join is not a function
TypeError: client.join is not a function


What I have tried :
I tried logging client to debug , it's not undefined.
Then I tried logging console.log(typeof  client); and the ouptput is object and not Socket.
